# Services in gitlab pipeline not working for Cucumber tests

Tags: spring-boot, mariadb, cucumber, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a spring boot application that I want to test in a pipeline with my Cucumber test. For this case, I have defined my application along with a mariadb service in the pipeline. Additionally, I have a small spring boot application as a fixture that encapsulates all database access for my tests. When the services are started, a liquibase script is executed against the MariaBD.

```yaml
variables:
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mariadb://mariadb:3306/zas?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
  MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
  FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true"
  CI_DEBUG_SERVICES: "true"


 test:
  stage: test
  image: gradle:7.6.0-jdk17-jammy
  needs: [ "docker-build-zas","docker-build-zas-fixture"]
  services:
    - name: selenium/standalone-chrome
      alias: selenium
    - name: mariadb
      alias: mariadb
    - name: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/zas-db:latest
      command:
        - "--url=jdbc:mariadb://mariadb:3306/zas?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC"
        - "--username=root"
        - "--password=root"
        - "--changeLogFile=/changelog/00.00.changelog.yaml"
        - "update"
    - name: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/zas:latest
      alias: zas
    - name: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/zas-fixture:latest
      alias: zas-fixture
  script:
    - echo "Running selenide tests..."
    - export ZAS_BASE_URI=http://zas:8080
    - export ZAS_FIXTURE_BASE_URI=http://zas-fixture:8082
    - gradle test -i -b zas-test/build.gradle
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - zas-test/build/report
```

Liquibase was executed successfully against the mariadb

```
UPDATE SUMMARY
Run:                         16
Previously run:               0
Filtered out:                 0
-------------------------------
Total change sets:           16
Liquibase command 'update' was executed successfully.
```

When I now run the Cucumber tests, they access the fixture, but the fixture complains that a table created by liquibase cannot be found.

What am I missing?